# Internal path in twig template

Tags: theming, 8, path-aliases, navigation

I'm trying to link to a Drupal path like "Contact Us" in my Twig template.
I've tried this code in my Twig template but I can't get any result.

```
<a href="{{ contact }}">{{ 'Contact'|t }}</a>
```

As well as this:

```
<a href="{{ path('contact') }}">{{ 'Contact'|t }}</a>
<a href="{{ url('contact') }}">{{ 'Contact'|t }}</a>
```

What is the correct way to link to an internal Drupal path in Twig?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `path()` & `url()` Drupal Twig functions expect a ***route name*** and will not work with a Drupal ***path***. For a relative/absolute path to **/contact**, you can use `path()`/`url()` respectively with the `contact.site_page` route:

```
<a href="{{ path('contact.site_page') }}">{{ 'Contact'|t }}</a>    
<a href="{{ url('contact.site_page') }}">{{ 'Contact'|t }}</a>
```

If you don't know your route name, what you're looking for is `link()`

```
{{ link('Contact'|t, 'base:contact', { 'class':[] }) }}
```

See [this d.o. page](https://www.drupal.org/node/2486991) for more explanation about these 3 functions and their differences.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and attention, and if you change this code to `'Contact'|t` Will be better :)

Comment: Done. It now matches the question.

Comment: If it is an internal link, wouldn't it have a route, and therefore be preferable to use the route name instead of the `base:` scheme?

Comment: That's a good point, I presumed OP didn't know his route so I offered `link()` as an alternative.